# 3px extra height on a div with an image inside it

Tags: html

I'm working on a new site but there is a small design thing which I just can't get my head around.

Basically, I'm creating a site which users are able to upload funny pictures to. Although the area where the picture is displayed there is a 3px gap underneath. *Here's a link to a screenshot of what I mean, dead link*.

I've tried a ton of things but nothing seems to work. If anyone can suggest any solution, please do.

Thanks.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's due to the default `vertical-align` value of images.  They are `baseline`.  Change to `top` or `bottom` and it will go away.

```
img{
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

The extra space is the area below the baseline which is for letters that hang below like `y` or `g`.

Comment: Awesome! Worked like a treat!