# Spaces below image, and html text in my newsletter template in Outlook.

Tags: html, css, email

I have some problem with my e-mail campaign.
I made all my boxes with correct width, height attribute, also made the img line-height to 0.1em and display them as block, so the question is on. What is this?

Every suggestion will be honored. Thanks.

```
<table width="594" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
<tbody><tr>
<td width="25" align="left" valign="top"></td>
    <td width="269" align="left" valign="bottom"> 
        <h1>{TITLE}</h1>
        <h2>{HOTEL} {HOTELCATEGORY}</h2>
        <p>{ROOM}</p>
        <p>{ACCOM}</p>
        <p>{START}</p>
        <p>{DATESTART} - {DATEEND}</p>
        <p>{DAYS} nap, {NIGHTS} éjszaka</p>
        <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="230" height="67">
            <tr height="11">
                <td width="80" height="11" align="left" valign="top"><img src="http://site.com/nwsltrv2/img/l_01_tl.png" width="80" height="11"></td>
                <td width="117" height="11" align="left" valign="top"><img src="http://site.com/nwsltrv2/img/l_01_t.png" width="117" height="11"></td>
                <td width="33" height="11" align="left" valign="top"><img src="http://site.com/nwsltrv2/img/l_01_tr.png" width="33" height="11"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr height="40">
                <td width="80" height="40" align="left" valign="top"><img src="http://site.com/nwsltrv2/img/l_01_l.png" width="80" height="40"></td>
                <td width="117" height="40" align="center" valign="middle" bgcolor="#444444"><b class="priceboxb" style="margin: 0; padding: 0;">{PRICE}{CURRENCY}</b><span class="priceboxspan" style="margin: 0; padding: 0;">/fõ</span></td>
                <td width="33" height="40" align="left" valign="top"><img src="http://site.com/nwsltrv2/img/l_01_r.png" width="33" height="40"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr height="16">
                <td width="80" height="16" align="left" valign="top"><img src="http://site.com/nwsltrv2/img/l_01_bl.png" width="80" height="16"></td>
                <td width="117" height="16" align="left" valign="top"><img src="http://site.com/nwsltrv2/img/l_01_b.png" width="117" height="16"></td>
                <td width="33" height="16" align="left" valign="top"><img src="http://site.com/nwsltrv2/img/l_01_br.png" width="33" height="16"></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </td>
    <td width="300" align="right" valign="top"> 
        <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
        <tr>
            <td width="10" height="11" align="left" valign="top"><img src="http://site.com/nwsltrv2/img/b_01_tl.png"></td>
            <td width="278" height="11" align="left" valign="top"><img src="http://site.com/nwsltrv2/img/b_01_t.png"></td>
            <td width="12" height="11" align="left" valign="top"><img src="http://site.com/nwsltrv2/img/b_01_tr.png"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td width="10" height="192" align="left" valign="top"><img src="http://site.com/nwsltrv2/img/b_01_l.png"></td>
            <td width="278" height="192" class="imageholder"><img src="{IMGSRC}" width="278" height="192" class="image" style="width: 278pt; height: 192pt; border:0; margin:0; padding:0;"></td>
            <td width="12" height="192" align="left" valign="top"><img src="http://site.com/nwsltrv2/img/b_01_r.png"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td width="10" height="12" align="left" valign="top"><img src="http://site.com/nwsltrv2/img/b_01_bl.png"></td>
            <td width="278" height="12" align="left" valign="top"><img src="http://site.com/nwsltrv2/img/b_01_b.png"></td>
            <td width="12" height="12" align="left" valign="top"><img src="http://site.com/nwsltrv2/img/b_01_br.png"></td>
        </tr>
        </table>
    </td>
    <td width="0" align="left" valign="top"></td>
</tr>
</tbody></table>
```

[image: this is the final view in Outlook]

Answer (score 3):

Looks like three pixels. What happens if you make the images that make up the label `display: block;` ?

Or take a look at this answer: [3px extra height on a div with an image inside it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10658475/3px-extra-height-on-a-div-with-an-image-inside-it)

Comment: Nop, i have both in my css code. :( `img{ display: block; vertical-align: top; border:0; height:auto; line-height:0.1%; outline:none; text-decoration:none; }`

Comment: Can you provide the rest of your CSS and what doctype is used? Is IE quirking?